# Is there a way to reach iCloud's Pages folder via the Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, icloud, cd

You can get to iCloud drive from the Terminal using `cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/`, but that doesn't show you all the same folders you see when you click the iCloud Drive link in the Finder's sidebar. It omits app-specific folders like Pages, Numbers, Keynote, Preview, etc. It only includes folders and files you've created that are outside of those app-specific folders.

Does anyone know how to `cd` to them in the Terminal?

Answer (score 4):

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~Pages/Documents/
```